# How to change module name?

Tags: excel, vbe

I am trying to change module names.  The "Rename" option is not given in the drop down list.  Am I missing some setting somewhere which is preventing renaming?

What I see on left click on module name

[image]

Comment: If you select your module, and on the top bar select "View" and "Properties Window", or alternatively just press `F4`, the properties window will pop up in your VB Explorer, with the option to change your module name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not how you rename a module.

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> and the properties pane will open... The `(Name)` will be there... change it in the properties pane.